# Send an imported swf to back of stage

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an imported swf but I can't seem to find a way to send it to the back of the stage in order to place buttons etc over the top. I've tried this:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Scene1.swf"); 
myLoader.load(url);                                     
addChild(myLoader);  

stage.setChildIndex(myLoader, -1);
```

Its not seeming to work with swf's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [addChildAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29)

```
addChildAt(myLoader,0);
```

Comment: Sorry, i was so busy. i tried to but it woudn't let me within 8 minutes.